# Failed to create folder in S3 bucket using boto3

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto3

I am trying to create a folder/directory in S3 bucket using boto3 library. Here is my sample code.

```py
import boto3

access_key = "REDACTED"
secret_key = "REDACTED"
endpoint = "http://REDACTED"

o = boto3.client(
  's3',
  endpoint_url=endpoint,
  aws_access_key_id=access_key,
  aws_secret_access_key=secret_key)

#MyBucket already exists
o.put_object(Bucket="MyBucket", Key="foo/")
```

Folder creation failed with the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/tst.py", line 14, in <module>
    o.put_object(Bucket="MyBucket", Key="foo/")
  File "/home/abhishek.kulkarni/nutest/my_nutest_virtual_env/lib/python2.7/site- packages/botocore/client.py", line 357, in _api_call
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
  File "/home/abhishek.kulkarni/nutest/my_nutest_virtual_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 661, in _make_api_call
    raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (MissingContentMD5ForObjectLock) when calling the PutObject operation: You must provide a Content-MD5 header with object lock fields.
```

Answer (score 0):

I saw this error on boto3==1.9. The error disappeared with boto3==1.17.112 python module version. The directory got created. No code change/addition is required.